# Binding two webviews together to play videos on youtube

Tags: c#, video, webview, youtube

I am trying to bind two webviews together so that one may behave in exactly the same way as the other. I have managed to get it binded using the uri of the other webview but the problem is that when I click on a video link, the uri remains the same and does not change, hence the other webview does nothing at that point.
Can I get them synchronized exactly the same so that playing a video in one would automatically play it in the other and same with the fullscreen feature?
Thanks.

```
var targetUri = await ContentView0Deg.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new String[] { "document.location.href;" });

Uri uri = new Uri(targetUri);
try {
    ContentView90Deg.Navigate(uri);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
    msg.ShowAsync();
}
```